# Abstract classes and Constructor issues and this UML diagram

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, uml, abstract-class

So I have to build some classes using this UML diagram.

[image]

I'm have trouble with Circle and Square.

I understand that Circle inherits from Ellipse, who inherits from Shape. I understand that when you use a subtype's constructor, the first line in the body should be super().

What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to do this with my diagram. I don't know where double r is going and I don't know how I can call super(x,y) when there is no constructor in Ellipse or Shape that take just those two parameters.
Same idea with square.

I get constructor errors when I follow the UML exactly.

Comment: show your code here and what errors you are having

Comment: This diagram is simply wrong. The "associations" (open triangle) need to be Generalizations (closed non-filled triangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circle is an ellipse that has both focal points at the same location i.e it's defined by only one radius. So if your circle constructor is:

```
Circle(double x, double y, double r)
```

Your need to call the ellipse constructor with:

```
super(x, y, r, r)
```

The same with square and rectangle.